# How to merge comment stream on Facebook events and my own website

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, comments

I have a website that allows people to post events and it automatically posts their events to facebook if they so choose. I also integrated facebook comments on the event pages on my website.

Is it possible to merge the comments that people leave on my website's event pages with the comments that people leave on the facebook event page that was automatically made for them? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Edit: Just to clarify: The comments on my website are done via the facebook-comments API, they are not a module of my application.

Comment: To further clarify: does your ideal situation involve a two-way connection between your website comments and the event's wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a separate answer, as after clarification it's significantly different.

If you want to basically have the wall of your event show up on your website, you can use the [Event API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) to pull in wallposts and display them.  To be able to post to that wall, you would have to do some custom coding to authenticate the user with publish_stream permission and then have a form on your site that would post to the event's wall, as noted in the [post section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#posts) of the above link.

Someone may have done this already and put code out there, but I doubt there is an easier way to get your ideal situation up and running.  This use case isn't as automagic as the comments box, unfortunately.

If you're just looking to spread your events socially, however, the comments box will post to the commenters' walls with a link to your event page, which can then in turn point them to the Faecbook event.  You *might* be able to use the Facebook event's URL as the URL for your comment box on the website, so it would just post a link directly to the Facebook event, but I'm not sure on that one.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this in my app, and we ended up deciding to just maintain separate streams.  This is because it's only a one-way integration - you can get comments from Facebook via the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/) and format them on your own website, in-line with your website comments, but there's no way to push comments from your website up to Facebook.

You could, if you wanted, just use the Facebook comment form for all comments - this has been done by big sites such as TechCrunch, and is effective, but it requires users to have a Facebook, AOL, Yahoo, or Hotmail account.  Whether you want to do that or not depends on your preferences and userbase.

Comment: Well, that's the idea. On my website's pages the comment stream is also done via Facebook, except that facebook has no idea that the webpage actually represents a FB event.

Comment: Oh!  I missed that bit in your post.  Hmm, it looks like doing that doesn't quite work like I (and probably you) would like - when someone comments, it posts to their wall, and then any comments on that post get added as replies to their comment on your website.

Answer (score 0):

there a tool that combines comments form different pages or different sources
Check https://feedgun.com which works on pulling comments from different sources like YouTube videos, existing wordpress sites, facebook comments plugins and even DIsqus account and combine them all together and publish them on any of your webpages, and it all works automatically once you set them where to pull and where to publish.